# Can Solr return the actual final query that was used when synonyms and stemming are used?

Tags: solr, synonym, stemming

I would like to be able to show in my UI what the query terms were that solr used to run the final query. For example, I might type the query "run" but behind the scenes solr will use stemming to also query "ran" and "running", I may also have a synonym defined which has "run = sprint".

I would like to show the user that although they typed in "run" the actual query was "run ran running sprint"

Any easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `debugQuery=on`. See [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#Why_does_id:archangel_come_before_id:hawkgirl_when_querying_for_.22wings.22) and [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyCookbook#Query_and_Analysis_Debugging).

Comment: Thanks Mauricio.
Do you know how much of a performance hit this is (if any)?
Would you know of any way to get the same information without the other debugging information?

It doesn't seem right to be using debugQuery in a production system.

Comment: @Pinguthepenguin: Re performance: measure it. It's not free, that's for sure, but I don't think it will be too slow either. I don't know any other way to do this, it's only available through debugQuery since it *is* a debugging tool and not something that is normally exposed to the end user.